# Transform datatable to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I would like to transform `z` to a dataframe for using `write_xlsx` . I try `z<-data.frame(z)`, but it didn't work. Any solution for this?

```
library(DT)
library(writexl)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


z<-datatable (Test, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                   paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollx=T),rownames = FALSE)


write_xlsx(z, 'C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/datas.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why don't you apply `write_xlsx` to `Test`?

Comment: Perhaps `write_xlsx(z$x$data, "...")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is under a couple layers so you have to fish it out. In this case it's in the 'x' element and under a table called 'data'. Often complicated structures like this (class(z) returns "datatables" "htmlwidget") will have the data nested like this, so it just takes a bit of digging.

```
as.data.frame(z$x$data)
```

Best,
Mostafa